# separable iff homeomorphic to totally bounded

Tags: metric-spaces

I'm having trouble with proving this theorem: A metric space is separable iff it is homeomorphic to a totally bounded metric space. There is a link on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space#cite_ref-Willard_1-1) to book by S. Willard, but it is stated there as a fact leaving it to the reader as an exercise to prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To Brian M. Scott: Separable => homeomorphic to a totally bounded space is causing trouble. To kahen: Isn't every totally bounded space separable? I'm not sure, but is it necessary to use the argument with completion?

Comment: @kahen: U cannot claim that "Any completion of Y is then compact" cos  closure of Y may not be equal to completion of Y!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you’re right that a totally bounded metric space is automatically separable, so that there’s no need to go through the completion: the union of finite $2^{-n}$-nets for $n\in\omega$ is a countable dense subset.

Now assume that $\langle X,d\rangle$ is a separable metric space. Without loss of generality assume that $d(x,y)\le 1$ for all $x,y\in X$, and let $D=\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$ be a dense subset of $X$. Define the map

$$f:X\to[0,1]^\omega:x\mapsto\big\langle d(x,x_n):n\in\omega\big\rangle\;.$$

Now show that $f$ is an embedding of $X$ into the compact metrizable space $[0,1]^\omega$, the Hilbert cube; being compact, the Hilbert cube is totally bounded in any compatible metric, and total boundedness is hereditary, so $f[X]$ is totally bounded in any metric inherited from $[0,1]^\omega$.

Comment: Can you tell me what's the meaning of $2^-n$-nets? More precisely, what's the meaning of a net?

Comment: @Frank: In this context an $\epsilon$-net in a metric space $\langle X,d\rangle$ is a set $A\subseteq X$ such that $X=\bigcup_{x\in A}B(x,\epsilon)$. Another way to say it is that for each $x\in X$ there is a $y\in A$ such that $d(x,y)<\epsilon$.

Comment: what does ω mean? And what is $[0,1]^ω$?

Comment: @Frank: $\omega$ is the set of natural numbers, $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$; you can replace it by $\Bbb N$ if you like. $[0,1]^\omega$ is the product of countably infinitely many copies of the space $[0,1]$.

Comment: U mean the amount of elements in D is uncertain and actually determined by the separpable set that u choose in X. So u use power N over [0,1] to build the hilbert cube. Besides, if the amount of elements in D is finite and supposed by m, then the power N should be fixed to m, is that right?

Comment: @Frank: No, that’s not right. $\Bbb N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ is the set of all non-negative integers. It’s an infinite set, and so is $D$.

Comment: @M.scott: oh. Actually, $[0,1]^N$ recalls me of the power set $2^N$ which represents all subset of N. So is there any difference between them? I mean I cannot understand why a set can be a power that should be a number.

Comment: @Frank: $[0,1]^{\Bbb N}$ and $2^{\Bbb N}$ are completely different things. $[0,1]^{\Bbb N}$ is the Cartesian product of countably infinitely many copies of the closed unit interval; equivalently, it’s the set of all infinite sequences of real numbers in $[0,1]$, since a point of the Cartesian product is a sequence of such real numbers. $2^{\Bbb N}$ is actually the Cartesian product of countably infinitely many copies of $\{0,1\}$ or, equivalently, the set of all infinite sequences of $0$’s and $1$’s. There is a $1$-$1$ correspondence between such sequences and subsets of $\Bbb N$, so some ...

Comment: ... people us the notation $2^{\Bbb N}$ for the power set of $\Bbb N$. This is potentially confusing until you really know what you’re doing, so I recommend that you use $\wp(\Bbb N)$ instead.

Comment: Make sense a little. Is [0,1]^card(N) equivalent to $[0,1]^N$?

Comment: @Frank: Yes, in this case.

Comment: Is {0,1}^card(N) equal to {0,1}^N?

Comment: @Frank: Provided that you’re thinking of them as Cartesian products, yes.

Comment: From the point of a set of all infinite sequences of 0’s and 1’s, {0,1}^card(N) will not be equal to ${0,1}^N$, right?

Comment: @Frank: They are both the set of all infinite sequences of zeroes and ones.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. I mean 2^card(N) is a number but 2^N is a set, right?

Comment: Sorry to bother u cos Im very interested in this problem. I've noticed the comment that "Provided that you’re thinking of them as Cartesian products, yes" and so from what, the answer will be no?

Comment: @Frank: In the most common formalizations of set theory **everything** is a set, and that includes cardinal numbers. For me $\Bbb N=\omega$, and $2^\omega$ can be a cardinal number or a set of sequences depending on context, though I prefer the notation ${}^\omega 2$ for the latter. This is really not something that can be resolved in a short conversation, especially when I don’t know how much formal set theory you know.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you introduce some books about it?

Comment: @Frank: Part of the problem is that I’m not sure exactly what ‘it’ is. Some of your questions are mostly about notation, and for that you just have to learn the conventions of the sources that you use. Some of it seems to be about cardinal arithmetic, and for that you want a serious introduction to set theory; [this one](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Edition-Revised-Expanded-Mathematics/dp/0824779150) is good, but it goes way beyond the minimum needed to get some idea of cardinal arithmetic and builds up a lot of machinery before getting to that point.

Comment: BTW, i've noticed that someone comment above with the opinion that "X homeomorphic to Y totally bounded. Any completion of Y is then compact and thus separable--by kahen". Actually, from my point of view, that "Y is then compact" is not correct because closure of Y may not be equal to completion of Y, is that right?

Comment: @Frank: No, kahen is correct, because a metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded. If $Y$ is totally bounded, so is its completion $\widetilde{Y}$, and since $\widetilde{Y}$ is also complete, it must be compact.

Comment: Y is isometric to a dense set D, the subset of completion Y' and since Y is totally bounded, D is totally bounded. And due to Y' = closure of D, Y' is totally bounded, is that right?

Comment: @Frank: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: I see ur claim of $[0,1]^N$ as hilbert cube. Actually, i've read the definition on wiki that is "The Hilbert cube is best defined as the topological product of the intervals [0, 1/n] for n = 1, 2, 3, 4, ... That is, it is a cuboid of countably infinite dimension", which is a little different from $[0,1]^N$. I haven't learned about hilbert cube before. So any form of Cartesian product of countably infinitely many closed intervals can be called as a hilbert cube, is that right?

Comment: Im still a little confusing on ur mapping, the f: X→$[0,1]^N$, that is how did u figure out this idea?

Comment: @Frank: This embedding of a separable metric space in the Hilbert cube is standard; I don’t know when I first encountered it, but it was many years ago.

Comment: wait, how to prove the f is one to one and onto, also continuous in order to show homeomorphism between X and the hilbert cube?

Comment: @Frank: Show that if $x\ne y$, there is an $n\in\omega$ such that $d(x,x_n)\ne d(y,x_n)$; it follows immediately that $f$ is $1$-$1$. In all likelihood $f$ is not onto; this doesn’t matter. Continuity is just a matter of checking that if $U$ is a basic open set in the product, then $f^{-1}[U]$ is open in $X$, which is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Ohhh, this f is really interesting: for example, X=[0,1] with usual metric and D is the set of rational numbers in [0,1] and then D is dense in X. However, if xn=0.1, x=0.05 and y = 0.15, d(x,xn)=|x-xn|=0.05=d(y,xn)=|y-xn|. However, there does exist many xn' not equal to 0.1 such that d(x,xn') ≠ d(y,xn'). What happened here?

Comment: @Frank: Nothing to worry about: as long as there is at least one $n$ such that $d(x,x_n)\ne d(y,x_n)$, you’ll have $f(x)\ne f(y)$. And since there is always such an $n$ whenever $x\ne y$, $f$ is $1$-$1$.

Comment: Why does it not matter when f is not onto? Cos onto is necessary for homeomorphism?

Comment: @Frank: $f$ is a homeomorphism of $X$ onto $f[X]$.

Comment: Ohh, got it. So we donnot need to find $f^{-1}$ either?

Comment: @Frank: Not explicitly, no.

Comment: f[X] is a subset of $[0,1]^ω$？

Comment: @Frank: Yes, it is.