# A metric space is separable if and only if it is homeomorphic to a totally bounded metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, separable-spaces

In the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space I found the following theorem:

> A metric space is separable if and only if it is homeomorphic to a totally bounded metric space.

I am struggling to prove the "$\Rightarrow$" direction. I found here in the forum these two attempts to build the desired homeomorphism:

1. [Separability, total boundness and topological equivalence of metrics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1061732/separability-total-boundness-and-topological-equivalence-of-metrics).
2. [separable iff homeomorphic to totally bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247532/separable-iff-homeomorphic-to-totally-bounded).

But I believe that in both cases these functions are not open, hence not homeomorphism.

Please help me find a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second link the inverse map is continuous: If $d(x^{j},x_n) \to d(x,x_n)$ for every $n$ then  then $d(x^{j},x)\to 0$.

Indeed, $d(x^{j},x)\leq d(x^{j},x_n)+d(x_n,x)$. First choose $n$ such that the second term is less than $\epsilon /2$ and then choose $m$ such that the first term is less than $\epsilon /2$ for $j \geq m$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why does such $m$ exist?

Comment: $d(x^{j},x_n) \to d(x,x_n)$ for the $n$ we have already chosen. SInce the limit here is less than $\epsilon/2$ all terms of the sequence $(d(x^{j},x_n))$ would also be less than $\epsilon/2$ for $j$ sufficiently large. @User31415